# How to jump to specific character on Mac OS X command line?

Tags: macos

I know that to jump to first character we have to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> for last character. But how do I jump to any character for example 4 character from start?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about a specific character count, but since the Mac OS X command line uses `bash` these shortcuts come close to what you want to do:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> lets you move forward one character.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> lets you move back one character.

And here are the rest:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> lets you go to the beginning of the line.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> lets you go to the end of the line.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> lets you retrieve the previous command.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> lets you retrieve the next command.
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> lets you move forward one word.
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> lets you move back one word.

More details [here](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but to shift by one character using arrow keys will work